# How to save (persist) bpy.ops.ptcache.bake_all() results?

Tags: python, animation, rigid-body-simulation, command-line

How to bake all rigid body dynamics via CLI? There are methods described over internet to bake fluid or soft bodies, but for rigid bodies I didn't find

## UPD

I've figured out that this can be done with such simple script:

```
import bpy
bpy.ops.ptcache.free_bake_all()
bpy.ops.ptcache.bake_all()
```

then run:

```
$ blender --background render_scene4.blend --python bake.py
```

And it seems to work because each frame baking time is similar to simulation time in blender GUI

**BUT**

After baking is finished (it reports `bake: done!`) I open the file in Blender.. And no bake data there. How to persist baking results?